# Apache, HTAccess, rewrite rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Hope you are fine.

I have a problem, if you can help me.

### #My rules (in this order):#

(WORKING:)

```
RewriteRule ^artists\/(.*[^discographies])\,([0-9]*)\/$ /artists/artist.php?id=$2 [L]
```

*URL:* /artists/B/barrington-levy,869/

---

(WORKING:)

```
RewriteRule ^artists\/(.*[^discographies])\,([0-9]*)\/discography\/$ /artists/discography.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

*URL:* /artists/B/barrington-levy,869/discography/

---

(WORKING:)

```
RewriteRule ^artists\/(.*[^discographies])\/$ /artists/alpha.php?id=$1 [L]
```

*URL:* /artists/B/

---

Now i need to make some new rules, and i suck !

---

**The first :**
/artists/discographies/1979/barrington-levy-shaolin-temple,85/

(NOT WORKING:)

```
RewriteRule ^artists\/discographies\/([0-9]*)\/(.*)\,[(0-9)*]\/$ /artists/disc.php?id=$4 [L]
```

---

**The second:**
/artists/discographies/2009-10/various-artists,jah-shaka-presents-the-positive-message,2563/

(NOT WORKING:)

```
RewriteRule ^artists\/discographies\/([0-9]*)\-([0-9]*)\/(.*)\,[(0-9)*]\/$ /artists/disc.php?id=$4 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `[(0-9)*]` try `([0-9]*)`

So for the entire rule replace:

```
RewriteRule ^artists\/discographies\/([0-9]*)\/(.*)\,[(0-9)*]\/$ /artists/disc.php?id=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^artists\/discographies\/([0-9]*)\-([0-9]*)\/(.*)\,[(0-9)*]\/$ /artists/disc.php?id=$4 [L]
```

With:

```
RewriteRule ^artists\/discographies\/([0-9]*)\/(.*)\,([0-9]*)\/$ /artists/disc.php?id=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^artists\/discographies\/([0-9]*)\-([0-9]*)\/(.*)\,([0-9]*)\/$ /artists/disc.php?id=$3 [L]
```

Comment: Also, unless I'm missing something, both the first and the third rule should have $3, not $4.